# Understanding Solution to Mathematical Olympiad Treasures 1.39

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, absolute-value

The question asks you to find values of x satisfying:

$|x - 3| + |x + 1| = 4$

The official solution's first step is:

$|x - 3| + |x + 1| \geq |(x - 3) - (x + 1)| = 4$

which makes sense to me

The next statement is:

"Equality occurs when $(x-3)(x+1) \leq 0$"

Where does that come from?

Comment: (x - 3)(x + 1) < 0 would imply exactly one of them is negative. WLOG assume (x - 3) were the negative one. Then you have |x - 3| = 3 - x and |x + 1| = x + 1 which gives the sum as 4.

Comment: If |x-3|+|x+1|=4 then  -1 <= x <= 3.  This is precisely when x-3 <= 0 and x+1 >= 0 which is precisely when (x-3)(x+1) <= 0.

Comment: I think the answer is $-1 \le x \le 3$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality is reached iff $(x-3)$ and $-(x+1)$ have the same sign. An equivalent condition is that $-(x-3)(x+1) \geq 0$, which is the same as $(x-3)(x+1) \leq 0$.